# How to get label by Id in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, label

I have the following label:

```
<label id="TWCv6" style="display:none">TWC</label>
```

I want to access it using its id plus Label selector to set its css. How can I do it?

Something like `$('label .TWCv6')`. Also I don't want to access using `For` attribute of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*using its id plus Label selector*

You need to prefix `#` when using [ID Selector `(“#id”)`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

*Use*

```
$('label#TWCv6')
```

Note: As Identifiers in HTML Must be unique. only `$('#TWCv6')` should work

Answer (score 0):

`$("label#TWCv6")` is what you are looking for